# Creating a steam library on flash drive problems

Tags: games, steam

Basically. I have steam installed but I want to install games onto a flash drive since I don't have enough space on the SSD.

When I try to add library folder on the flash drive I get this message
"New steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions"

If I try to install the game straight to the folder I get the same message.

Please could someone give me a tutorial or tell me how to fix it so I can complete the task. Step by step would be nice!

Comment: Is the Flash drive formatted to NTFS?

Comment: No, it's formatted to FAT32.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Comment: That's no better. You have to mount the drive with execute permissions (as shown in the linked question). The mount type for FAT32 is `vfat`.

Comment: Please can you give me a better tutorial than that, I've no clue on where to go from that topic

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments:

Find out what is the name of your drive:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This lists all partitions, there you have to find yours (just look for the size in the first line, this usually helps most)

Then execute

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,auto,user,exec,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/DRIVE /mountpoint
```

where `DRIVE` is substituted by what you found out above and `mountpoint`, for example, is `/media/$USER/steamDrive`.

If you want to always mount this drive on boot see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab); which also might be a good idea to read for understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm just going to have to give up. Doing sudo fdisk -l leads to it not being there. On top of that when trying to eject the flash drive it's saying medium are busy after only just putting it in.

Comment: does it stay busy after a while? It might be that it is "busy" mounting

Comment: It's fine now. Would it be easier if I just formatted the flash drive to ext4 format?

Comment: if you only use it on ubuntu I'd say yes; you are able to manage the permissions right then
Mounting however is necessary nevertheless - `sudo mount /dev/DRIVE /mountpoint`

Comment: the fstab entry would be sth like `/dev/DRIVE /mountpoint ext4 defaults 0 2` (explanation see link above); then you mount it every time you boot

Comment: So no matter what I'm going to have to mount?

Comment: yes otherwise you cant use your drive; if you like the gui-way more you can mount in nautilus too (just click the "Home" Button in the launcher and there click the drive). This mounts at `/media/$USER/drivename`

Comment: or you even might try [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/60817/how-to-auto-mount-partitions-at-linux-startup-the-easy-way/); however I just googled it - never used this myself

Comment: the great thing about mounting is, that you can choose the mountpoint, win just adds another letter for the drive. In the Linux way you can easily extend your /home if you are out of space with no need to navigate to D:\Data